# Relation Between Normalizations

Tags: normalization

say we have a fixed table T. Is there a unique normalized version of T,
i.e., does the/a correct normalization, say up to 3NF produce a unique table up to
some equivalence? Basically, I am trying to find out how many different correct ways of normalizing a table there are.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are often more then one ways to normalize a relation. An example:

Relation `R (ABCD)` with functional dependencies:

```
A -> BCD
B -> CD
C -> BD
```

Can be normalized to 3NF either:

```
R1 (AB)     A -> B

R2 (BCD)    B -> CD
            C -> BD
```

or:

```
R1 (AC)     A -> C

R2 (BCD)    B -> CD
            C -> BD
```

or:

```
R1 (AB)     A -> B

R2 (BC)     B -> C
            C -> B

R3 (BD)     B -> D
```

or: lots of other ways ...

Comment: Thank you. Is there some equivalence between two normalizations D1, D2, i.e., given two normalizations D1, D2 of the same database is there some sort of function f so that f(D2)=D1 or f(D1)=D2? Or is there a way of knowing if two databases D1, D2 are both normalizations of  the same database?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I guess by comparing the dependencies they have (preserved)?

Comment: I am thinking of something like the relation of homeomorphism or isomorphism in Mathematics, between tables. Maybe there is a relation between the two dependency diagrams, as you said.

Comment: I assume the keys would be fixed to start with too, right? This would restrict the normalizations that preserve both keys and relations.

Comment: The only key in the above `R` is `A`. In the normalizations below, `B` is also a key in some relations and `C` in some others. So, the keys may differ, depending on the NF.

Comment: Thank you, please give me some time to think it through and get back to you; sorry I was not able to make it more precise.